How to generate std::array of primes up to certain maximum prime at compile-time
I am trying to generate std::array with primes up to 30. Not first 30 primes, but 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29.
My best attempt is below and it works, but has ugly code repetition:
auto primes = make_primes(MAX_PRIME);
constexpr auto N = make_primes(MAX_PRIME).size();

Is there some way to avoid it?
Link: https://godbolt.org/z/dTvvGj6sY
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

constexpr vector<int> make_primes(int max_prime) noexcept
{
    vector<int> primes;

    primes.push_back(2);
    for (int p = 3; p < max_prime; )
    {
        primes.push_back(p);

        int i;
        do {
            p += 2;

            i = 1;
            for (; i < primes.size(); ++i)
            {
                if ((p % primes[i]) == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (i != primes.size());
    }
    
    return primes;
}

constexpr int MAX_PRIME = 30;  // 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29

constexpr auto primes {
    []() {
        auto primes = make_primes(MAX_PRIME);
        constexpr auto N = make_primes(MAX_PRIME).size();

        std::array<int, N> arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
            arr[i] = primes[i];
        return arr;
    }()
};

int main()
{
    cout << primes.size() << ':';
    for (int x : primes)
        cout << ' ' << x;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}


Being able to use std::vector in constexpr allows to resuse the code as you did instead of requiring 2 similar algo, one for the size, and one to fill the array. I don't think there is a way to avoid to call the function twice currently.

@Jarod42, I wasn't aware that one could use std::vector in constexpr. How can it be done at compile time since it has somewhere to deal with dynamic allocation ?

@edrezen: constexpr std::vector is indeed not possible, but using std::vector in constexpr function as OP did is possible.

I did something like this 5 years ago: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ODZ2TL4VgjJv6b0c

The issue is that you need first to compute the size of the array before allocate it and then populate it.
A variation on your proposal is to make make_primes return as a std::pair both the computed size and a populated array (whose size is equal to 30). Then you can use the computed size as a template parameter of a cut function that will cut the array with the good size.
The difference compared to you proposal is that make_primes is called only once.
#include <array>

template<int max_prime>
constexpr auto make_primes () noexcept
{
    static_assert(max_prime>0);
    
    std::array<int,max_prime> primes {};

    int idx=0;
    primes[idx++] = 2;
    
    for (std::size_t p = 3; p < max_prime; )
    {
        primes[idx++] = p;

        int i;
        do {
            p += 2;
            i = 1;
            for (; i < idx; ++i)
            {
                if ((p % primes[i]) == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        while (i != idx);
    }
    
    return std::make_pair(primes,idx);
}

template<std::size_t P, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto cut (std::array<int,N> const& in)
{
    static_assert (P<=N);
    std::array<int,P> out;
    for (std::size_t i=0; i<P; i++)  { out[i] = in[i]; } 
    return out;
}

constexpr auto prinfo = make_primes<30>();
constexpr auto primes = cut<prinfo.second> (prinfo.first);

static_assert (primes.size() == 10);
static_assert (primes == std::array {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29});

int main()  { }

Demo
Update 1: some simplification according to @Jarod42's comment.
Update 2: a small improvement that provides a clearer API for the end user.
Update 3: a final one that relies on std::span

Good point, I had also to change the type to std::size_t in order not to mix int and unsigned long int for template parameter N

That requires to know the upper limit of the array size. Which is easy for primes OP example, but it is not necessary the case (using series from Collatz_conjecture).

Ah, this is the Syracuse conjecture ? I didn't know it had also this name.

Not sure what you understand, but I meant, that for a function like getCollatzSerie<N>(); Demo, upper limit is harder (if possible) to know .

No, no, I got your point, you may have algorithms that produce more entries than the provided constant input; I just noticed that I didn't know that the Syracuse and the Collatz conjectures were the same beast. I doubt however that you can find a counterexample of the conjecture through c++ compile time features ;)

This is code I have lying around that does that :
E.g. for first 10 numbers it will generate an array with exactly 4 values only
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

namespace details
{

    template<std::size_t N>
    static constexpr auto sieve()
    {
        std::array<bool, N> is_prime{};

        for (std::size_t n = 2; n < N; ++n)
        {
            is_prime[n] = true;
        }


        for (std::size_t n = 2ul; n < N; ++n)
        {
            if (is_prime[n])
            {
                auto n2 = n * n;
                for (std::size_t m = n2; m < N; m += n)
                {
                    is_prime[m] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return is_prime;
    }

    template<std::size_t N>
    static constexpr std::size_t count_primes(const std::array<bool, N>& is_prime)
    {
        std::size_t count{ 0ul };

        for (std::size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        {
            if (is_prime[n]) ++count;
        }

        return count;
    }

    template<std::size_t N>
    static constexpr auto get_primes()
    {
        std::array<int, count_primes<N>()> primes{};
        auto is_prime = sieve<N>();

        for (std::size_t n = 0ul, i = 0ul; n < N; ++n)
        {
            if (is_prime[n])
            {
                primes[i] = static_cast<int>(n);
                ++i;
            }
        }

        return primes;
    }

} // details

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto make_primes()
{
    constexpr auto is_prime = details::sieve<N>();
    constexpr auto count = details::count_primes<N>(is_prime);
    std::array<int, count> primes{};

    for (std::size_t n{ 0ul }, i{ 0ul }; n < N; ++n)
    {
        if (is_prime[n])
        {
            primes[i] = static_cast<int>(n);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return primes;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto primes = make_primes<10>();
    static_assert(primes.size() == 4ul);
    static_assert(primes[0] == 2);
    static_assert(primes[1] == 3);
    static_assert(primes[2] == 5);
    static_assert(primes[3] == 7);

    for (const auto prime : primes)
    {
        std::cout << prime << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}



This doesn't solve the OP issue since count_primes need to call sieve first, and the sieve function actually find out the number of primes and their value. Also it has an error here std::array<int, count_primes<N>()> primes{}; since count_primes needs a parameter (the sieve result).


@xryl669: in fact, get_primes() can completely be removed as unused.

BTW +1 for using the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, you can make it give the whole result in a single call (simply by decounting at first each time you dismiss a non prime number and then simply fill the array in that function): create an array of N integer, the compute the sieve by decrementing the count for non prime and emptying the array at the same time, via swapping with last element). In the end, copy the begginning of the array to the number of primes found

count_primes and filling the array duplicates the logic (which is mostly the 2 calls from OP).

I first create an array that only flags which numbers are prime and then condense them in a second  array only containing the prime numbers.

To better explain my comment on @PepijnKramer, here's the code:
template<std::size_t N>
static constexpr auto sieve()
{
    // Compute both the prime number array and count them at the same time
    constexpr auto fc = []() {
        std::array<bool, N> is_prime{};
        std::array<int, N> tmp{};
        for (std::size_t n = 2; n < N; ++n)
            is_prime[n] = true;
        std::size_t c = 0;
        for (std::size_t n = 2ul; n < N; ++n)
        {
            if (is_prime[n])
            {
                auto n2 = n * n;
                for (std::size_t m = n2; m < N; m += n)
                {
                    is_prime[m] = false;
                }
                tmp[c++] = n;
            }
        }
        return std::make_pair(c, tmp);
    }();

    // Then strip the array to the final (used/counted) size 
    std::array<int, fc.first> result;
    for (auto i = 0; i < fc.first; i++) result[i] = fc.second[i];
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr auto a = sieve<30>();
    for (auto i : a)
       std::cout << i << std::endl;    
}

Demo
You can compute both if a number is prime and count it at the same time (in that case, you'll save it in a oversized array). Then a final step is to cut the array to the actual used numbers and return that.
Please note that this isn't optimized at all and just used as a proof of concept. The Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm is far from being optimal, you can remove all even numbers in a very easy step and avoid creating a N sized array as a temporary storage (a N/2 array is enough for N > 2).
